# Mysql IN Condition Limiting

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables, one for Strains, and one for StoreStrains. Stores sell strains so there can be multiple entries in "StoreStrains" for a certain strain_id.

I'm making a one call to grab all Strains from Strain table. Then I'm mapping those strain_ids like so "1,2,3,4,5". Then I'm doing another SQL call to find what stores have those strains.

```
SELECT * FROM StoreStrains
WHERE strain_id IN (strain_ids)
LIMIT 5
```

As you could expect, this will return all StoreStrains with a strain_id of 1-5. But if 3 of those stores carry the same strain, I it would return 8 results, but I'm limiting to 5.

On a larger scale (in a DB with 500,000+ StoreStrains), just increasing the limit to "get all the results" isn't a good option at all. So I'm wondering if there is a way limit

```
WHERE strain_id IN (strain_ids)
```

To 1 result per?

I know I could just do 5 separate SQL calls like this:

```
SELECT * FROM StoreStrains Where strain_id = ? LIMIT 1
```

But I would much prefer this all happens in one sql call if possible. Thank you.

Comment: If you want one StoreStrain for one Strain, what is the criteria to select one of them? Which StoreStrain should be shown?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to arbitrarily pick a store, then do this

```
Select strain_id,
       (Select StrainStore.id
        from StrainStore
        Where StrainStore.strain_id = Strains.strain.id
        Limit 1)
From Strains
```

But it's probably better to do this

```
Select Strains.strain_id, GROUP_CONCAT(StrainStore.id)
From Strains
Join StrainStore
    On (Strains.strain_id = StrainStore.strain_id)
Group by Strains.strain_id
```